# Using getpass with python 2 and 3 compatibility

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, character-encoding

I know that `getpass` returns an unicode string in Python 3 and some kind of `str` in Python 2. However, I'm not sure about the encoding on Python 2.

How can I transform the value it returns to an UTF-8 encoded `bytes` object in a way that works in both Python 2 and 3?

(I don't use `six` and am trying to write code that just works on both, rather than `if`fing on the version number.)

Comment: `p.decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode("utf-8")`

Comment: Did you try `from __future__ import unicode_literals`?

Comment: @wenzul, Python 3 strings don't have a `decode` method, but I may be able to derive something that works from that.

Comment: @Zopieux, that shouldn't have anything to do with this, since no literals are involved.

Comment: What are you expecting as output? Can you give an example?

Comment: @AnandSKumar, I'm expecting a `bytes` object that has the string UTF-8 encoded. I.e. if I input the character 'ä', I would expect `b'\xc3\xa4'`. (Which in Python 2 is also equivalent to `'\xc3\xa4'`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow the [***EAFP***](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) policy in this case. Try to decode() and encode() the string assuming its a python 2 environment, and expect `TypeError` , and if you get the TypeError , just do `encode()` . Example -

```
import sys
import getpass

s = getpass.getpass()

try:
    u = s.decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode('UTF-8')
except TypeError:
    u = s.encode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, at least. An unnecessary `try` isn't very nice, though, so I'll leave this unaccepted for a while to see if other solutions appear.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `getpass()` returns a normal Python 2 string, i.e. a byte string. It uses the terminal's encoding, so if the terminal is set to use UTF-8 you don't need to do anything - the string it returns will already be a UTF-8 encoded byte string. But to be robust, you can do this:

```
import sys
from getpass import getpass

p = getpass()
if isinstance(p, bytes):
    p = p.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
p = p.encode('utf-8') # :D
```

We use `if isinstance(p, bytes):` to stop Python 3 from touching the string returned by `getpass()`, and then we encode the Unicode to UTF-8

Comment: @otus: My new version should work properly on Python 3. But if it doesn't please let me know.